# c# fix wpf container to avoid pulling it with mouse

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf-application in visual studio 2017.
On a grid-Container I have some Labels and TextBoxes. I would like to mark them all to move them. But I cant pull the mouse over these components because i will grab the grid and move the grid instead of marking.
How can I fix the grid so I can mark several Controls with the mouse?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the Visual Studio tag, which is appropriate for this question.

Comment: This isn't the answer you're looking for; but I don't use the XAML designer to position things. I just use.it to see the layout. I create.my UI simply.by editing the XAML. I find that if I use the designer, it puts in hard-coded values, rather than taking an approach like anchoring used to do in WinForms, where things self-size.

Comment: Is there another Designer where I can mark and move Controls using C# and wpf? I'd really like to know that.

Comment: Microsoft's Blend can also allow you to edit XAML.

Comment: ok but, i have about 37 controls on the grid, so if I want to move them, i dont want to edit every single xaml-entry ^^

Answer (score 0):

In general, In the [Document Outline] or press [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>], you can select the UI components in the layout and move them to a different parent component.

This is very useful when you need to move child objects to a different parent without touching UI and worrying about any unnecessary changes.

Comment: ok thx. But then I can also simply mark the controls in the designer window. I dont need the Document Outline for that - or is it possible to chose all textboxes at the same time?

Comment: I meant you can drag and drop it within the document outline when you move the ui component.   You can also multi-select if you press and hold the ctrl button while the ui component is selected.